# Limit macro to set a range for textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to link a range of cells to a text box, the only problem is if I edit the text box, it will write in any cell. I want to limit that ability to a specific range ("C4 to C11"). Here is my code:

```
Dim PreviousCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Column = 3 Then ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text = Target



       If Not PreviousCell Is Nothing Then
       Debug.Print PreviousCell.Address
       End If

       Set PreviousCell = Target ' This needs to be the last line of code.

End Sub



Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, my english may not be good, but I don't get what are you trying to accomplish. You mean that if you select a cell in Range `C4:C11` then you want the textbox show the value of selected cell?

Comment: It already does that, if I click on a random cell, not in column 3, I can edit that cell via the text box. I only want to be able to edit column 3 via the text box.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If ActiveCell.Column = 3 Then ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1

End Sub
```